# Unmarshal 2 different structs in a slice

Tags: arrays, go, struct

My input json data is this (cannot be changed, from an external resource):

```
[{
   "Url": "test.url",
   "Name": "testname"
},{ 
   "FormName": "Test - 2018",
   "FormNumber": 43,
   "FormSlug": "test-2018"
}]
```

I have two structs that will always match the data within the array:

```
type UrlData struct{
  "Url"  string `json:Url` 
  "Name" string `json:Name` 
}

type FormData struct{
  "FormName"  string `json:FormName` 
  "FormNumber" string `json:FormNumber` 
  "FormSlug" string `json:FormSlug`
}
```

Obviously the code below will not work, but is it possible at the top level (or otherwise) to declare something like this:

```
type ParallelData [
 urlData UrlData
 formData FormData
]
```

Comment: Just as a general note about the struct tags, a) they're invalid as written, it should be e.g. `json:"Url"` (note the quotes), and b) they're totally unnecessary, the default name of a field in JSON is the name of the field in the struct, so a struct tag explicitly giving the same name is redundant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a two step process for unmarshaling. First, unmarshal a list of arbitrary JSON, then unmarshal the first and second element of that list into their respective types.

You can implement that logic in a method called UnmarshalJSON, thus implementing [the json.Unmarshaler interface](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler). This will give you the compound type you are looking for:

```
type ParallelData struct {
    UrlData  UrlData
    FormData FormData
}

// UnmarshalJSON implements json.Unmarshaler.
func (p *ParallelData) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var records []json.RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &records); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if len(records) < 2 {
        return errors.New("short JSON array")
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(records[0], &p.UrlData); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(records[1], &p.FormData); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Try it on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/QMn_rbJj-P-

Comment: Great Answer, Output is exactly as expected! Thanks Peter, and everyone else who has responded!

Answer (score 4):

I think [Answer of Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48701156/3427852) is awesome.

**Option 1:**

```
type ParallelData [
 urlData UrlData
 formData FormData
]
```

if you need above structure then you can define it as

```
type UrlData struct {
    Url  string `json:"Url,omitempty"`
    Name string `json:"Name,omitempty"`
}
type FormData struct {
    FormName   string `json:"FormName,omitempty"`
    FormNumber string `json:"FormNumber,omitempty"`
    FormSlug   string `json:"FormSlug,omitempty"`
}
type ParallelData struct {
    UrlData  UrlData  `json:"UrlData,omitempty"`
    FormData FormData `json:"FormData,omitempty"`
}
```

In this case, your json will look like

```
[  
   {  
      "UrlData":{  
         "Url":"test.url",
         "Name":"testname"
      }
   },
   {  
      "FormData":{  
         "FormName":"Test - 2018",
         "FormNumber":"43",
         "FormSlug":"test-2018"
      }
   }
]
```

**Option 2:**

You've provide following json:

```
[  
   {  
      "Url":"test.url",
      "Name":"testname"
   },
   {  
      "FormName":"Test - 2018",
      "FormNumber":43,
      "FormSlug":"test-2018"
   }
]
```

If your json really look like, then you can use following `struct`

```
type UrlData struct {
    Url  string `json:Url`
    Name string `json:Name`
}

type FormData struct {
    FormName   string `json:FormName`
    FormNumber int    `json:FormNumber`
    FormSlug   string `json:FormSlug`
}

type ParallelData struct {
    UrlData
    FormData
}
```

For both options, you can Unmarshall your json like this

```
var parallelData []ParallelData
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &parallelData)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(parallelData)
```

See option 1 in <kbd>[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XvtBDESk8kD)</kbd>

See option 2 in <kbd>[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/urllP6GGzag)</kbd>

Comment: As I commented on a deleted answer, this will cause trouble when marshalling and when `omitempty` is forbidden by the protocol (i.e. it requires empty strings to be present). And it is not really an option to change input.

Comment: @leafbebop,
What do you think if I remove `omitempty` from `struct`. This will work fine too. Right? As, OP is marshalling from json to struct. It doesn't matter. Right?

Comment: You can try it. I think it will prints both struct and becomes even more messy.

Comment: @leafbebop, Is there any other way to use two struct and also get clean json without `omitempty`?

Comment: Write custom MarshalJSON method over it. Only one I can think of. Not idiomatic, though.

Comment: @AbuHanifa, `FormName *string 'json:"FormName,omitempty"'` You can also use this. Then if you set `FormName=nil`, it will be ignored in JSON. If you set `FormName=""`, it will be in JSON.

Comment: this doesn't work if the items are many or in different order. Result is: 
[{UrlData:{Url:test.url Name:testname} FormData:{FormName: FormNumber:0 FormSlug:}} {UrlData:{Url: Name:} FormData:{FormName:Test - 2018 FormNumber:43 FormSlug:test-2018}}]

Answer (score 1):

You can unmarshal into a `map[string]interface{}` for example:

```
type ParallelData map[string]interface{}

func main() {
    textBytes := []byte(`[
    {
      "Url": "test.url",
      "Name": "testname" 
    },
    {
      "FormName": "Test - 2018",
      "FormNumber": 43,
      "FormSlug": "test-2018"
    }]`)
    var acc []ParallelData
    json.Unmarshal(textBytes, &acc)

    fmt.Printf("%+v", acc)
}
```

Output:

```
=> [map[Url:test.url Name:testname] map[FormName:Test - 2018 FormNumber:43 FormSlug:test-2018]]
```

<sub>[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2P4bq6CpxZ5)</sub>

Comment: It doesn't use the two structs. I think it is better to remove the definition to avoid confusion?

Comment: Thanks for the response. But is it possible to take this Idea further and somehow convert each mapped interface into their respective struct?

Comment: I assume you can, with some sort of remarshaling, but what the point?

Comment: I'm using AWS Step Functions and the lambda package marshals json input automatically. Unfortunately this is the way the data is passed via Parallel step function to my code. That's why ideally it would need to be a top level defined array, but that doesn't seem to be possible to do in golang...

Comment: It's still unclear for me why you need the structs and why the _array_ `[]map[string]interface{}` doesn't work for you.

Comment: @RomanKiselenko five years later you probably lie awake at night thinking about these comments you made, but it should be obvious: for type safety.