# Go How do you deserialize a JSON array of mixed types

Tags: arrays, json, go

I'm writing a go client for [aigaming.com](https://www.aigaming.com), and when I make an invalid request the response will include some error information. I want to capture this response with a `struct`, however, I run into trouble when the types begin to mix.

The JSON structure of the error data looks like this:

```
{  
   "errorMessage":"An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value: One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string for key :v0",
   "errorType":"ClientError",
   "stackTrace":[  
      [  
         "/var/task/OfferGame.py",
         612,
         "lambda_handler",
         "game = offerGame.createOffer()"
      ],
      [  
         "/var/task/OfferGame.py",
         586,
         "createOffer",
         "gameRow = self.findSuitableWaitingGame()"
      ],
      [  
         "/var/task/OfferGame.py",
         503,
         "findSuitableWaitingGame",
         "Key('GameStyleId_GameStatus').eq(str(self.gameStyleId) + '_' + self.Game.KEY_GAME_STATUS_WAITING)"
      ]
      // There are more items, but I'll omit them for brevity
   ]
}
```

This is mostly trivial to capture, however, the trouble comes with the `stackTrace` items. It is an array, of arrays, of mixed types.

The best results I've had so far are with this struct. It doesn't actually give me any data (all the elements are empty), but it comes back with the correct number of elements and nested elements to have.

```
type ErrorResponse struct {
    ErrorMessage string          `json:"errorMessage"`
    ErrorType    string          `json:"errorType"`
    StackTrace   [][]interface{} `json:"stackTrace"`
}
```

Is there a way to parse these items of mixed type? Can I possibly work around this by somehow forcing all the integer elements to be treated as strings instead?

UPDATE:
Here is what I mean by "empty". The correct number of things are there, but they do not appear to be initialized.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unmarshal 2 different structs in a slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48697961/unmarshal-2-different-structs-in-a-slice)

Comment: What do you mean by *"It doesn't actually give me any data (all the elements are empty)"*? To me it seems your code should work without a problem https://play.golang.org/p/ENGjPf_wZWT.

Comment: @mkopriva I've included a screenshot. Thanks for pointing out that wasn't clear enough. As you can see, the right number of "things" are there, but they aren't actually initialized to the data they should be.

Comment: @PaulNelsonBaker I'm sorry but it's still not clear to me what's missing, can you be more specific what pieace of data that is in the json is missing from the struct value? Please see here https://play.golang.org/p/-R_bC91_ymg

Comment: @mkopriva I see the issue now. I was looking at the debugger and I assumed that I was seeing empty values. As your example shows: printing the values themselves shows that the debugger isn't revealing the correct data, even though it is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, just continue. Whenever you need something from StackTrace, use [type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) and execute code according to the actual type. Do note that type assertions return 2 values, check the second one to see whether the assumed type is correct or not.

Comment: This IS actually the correct thing to do. I mis-understood what I was seeing. The debugger is showing blank spaces, which I assumed meant there was no data loaded. The data is there. Now I we can perform logic upon it.

Answer (score 1):

Implement StackTrace's line as [json.Unmarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) and use like this:

```golang
type ErrorResponse struct {
    ErrorMessage string           `json:"errorMessage"`
    ErrorType    string           `json:"errorType"`
    StackTrace   []StackTraceLine `json:"stackTrace"`
}

type StackTraceLine struct {
    A string
    B int64
    C string
    D string
}

func (l *StackTraceLine) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    return json.Unmarshal(data, &[]interface{}{&l.A, &l.B, &l.C, &l.D})
}

func main() {
    var res ErrorResponse
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{  
                "errorMessage":"An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value: One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string for key :v0",
                "errorType":"ClientError",
                "stackTrace":[  
                    [  
                        "/var/task/OfferGame.py",
                        612,
                        "lambda_handler",
                        "game = offerGame.createOffer()"
                    ],
                    [  
                        "/var/task/OfferGame.py",
                        586,
                        "createOffer",
                        "gameRow = self.findSuitableWaitingGame()"
                    ],
                    [  
                        "/var/task/OfferGame.py",
                        503,
                        "findSuitableWaitingGame",
                        "Key('GameStyleId_GameStatus').eq(str(self.gameStyleId) + '_' + self.Game.KEY_GAME_STATUS_WAITING)"
                    ]
                ]
            }`), &res)
}
```

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/MM2WLJW0ksY)

Answer (score 0):

Unmarshal json into generic `interface`

```
jsonstr := []byte(`{  
                "errorMessage":"An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value: One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string for key :v0",
                "errorType":"ClientError",
                "stackTrace":[  
                    [  
                        "/var/task/OfferGame.py",
                        612,
                        "lambda_handler",
                        "game = offerGame.createOffer()"
                    ],
                    [  
                        "/var/task/OfferGame.py",
                        586,
                        "createOffer",
                        "gameRow = self.findSuitableWaitingGame()"
                    ],
                    [  
                        "/var/task/OfferGame.py",
                        503,
                        "findSuitableWaitingGame",
                        "Key('GameStyleId_GameStatus').eq(str(self.gameStyleId) + '_' + self.Game.KEY_GAME_STATUS_WAITING)"
                    ]
                ]
            }`)

    var dat interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonstr, &dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Loop through underlying `map[string]interface{}`

```
for _, value := range dat.(interface{}).(map[string]interface{}){
    switch tt := value.(type){
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("type is string", tt)
    case float64:
        fmt.Printf("type is float64", tt)
    case bool:
        fmt.Printf("type is boolean", tt)
    case interface{}:
        fmt.Printf("type is interface{}", tt)
    default:
        fmt.Printf("type is unknown", tt)

    }
}
```

Finally using `switch` you can check the type of value which you can get using type assertion.

check the code on [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hofWPb_oqaf)