# How do I json unmarshal slice inside a slice

Tags: json, go

I am trying to unmarshal some pretty ugly json but can't figure out how. I have:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

type PublicKey struct {
    ID     int    `json:"id"`
    Key    string `json:"key"`
    MyData []struct {
        ID    string `json:"id"`
        Value int    `json:"value"`
    }
}

func main() {
    b := `[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "key": "my_key"
  },
  [
    {
      "id": "some_id",
      "value": 12
    },
    {
      "id": "anorther_id",
      "value": 13
    }
  ]
]`

    var pk []PublicKey
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(b), &pk)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(pk)

}
```

For the result I am getting:

```
[{1 my_key []} {0  []}]
```

The second slice is empty when it shouldn't be.

**EDIT**:
The error I get is:

```
json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field PublicKey.key of type main.PublicKey
```

https://play.golang.org/p/cztXOchiiS5

Comment: Don't ignore error, it has a hint.

Comment: What result would you like to get? A slice of three PublicKeys? A slice of two PublicKeys, where the second has a MyData slice of length two?

Comment: @ferhatelmas oops! added it.

Comment: @robx the latter.

Comment: @robx: to clarify there would be 1 PublicKey that has a MyData slice along with the  top-level "ID" and "Key" fields.

Comment: So, this sample data isn't the correct one but something you artificially generate to match your struct ?

Comment: updated your sample https://play.golang.org/p/EE7mwRsyb8g

Comment: @ferhatelmas No, the sample data is correct. Your update has a key and mine doesn't and that's why yours works.

Comment: Why are you mixing arrays and objects in the top level ? How is it generated ? It makes parsing unnecessarily more difficult.

Comment: @ferhatelmas I'm not. That's the data that is given me. Like I said, it is ugly data. My question is how can I unmarshal it?

Comment: Do you want to unmarshal all the keys into the same Public Key array? Or match the JSON strictly?

Comment: Would like to match the JSON but whatever works is fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unmarshal 2 different structs in a slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48697961/unmarshal-2-different-structs-in-a-slice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is some truly hideous JSON! I have two approaches to handling the mixed array elements and I like the 2nd one better. Here's the first approach using `interface` and a type switch:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type PublicKey struct {
    ID  int    `json:"id"`
    Key string `json:"key"`
}

type MyData struct {
    ID    string `json:"id"`
    Value int    `json:"value"`
}

type MixedData struct {
    Key    []PublicKey
    MyData [][]MyData
}

func (md *MixedData) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    md.Key = []PublicKey{}
    md.MyData = [][]MyData{}
    var obj []interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(b), &obj)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, o := range obj {
        switch o.(type) {
        case map[string]interface{}:
            m := o.(map[string]interface{})
            id, ok := m["id"].(float64)
            if !ok {
                return errors.New("public key id must be an int")
            }
            pk := PublicKey{}
            pk.ID = int(id)
            pk.Key, ok = m["key"].(string)
            if !ok {
                return errors.New("public key key must be a string")
            }
            md.Key = append(md.Key, pk)
        case []interface{}:
            a := o.([]interface{})
            myData := make([]MyData, len(a))
            for i, x := range a {
                m, ok := x.(map[string]interface{})
                if !ok {
                    return errors.New("data array contains unexpected object")
                }
                val, ok := m["value"].(float64)
                if !ok {
                    return errors.New("data value must be an int")
                }
                myData[i].Value = int(val)
                myData[i].ID, ok = m["id"].(string)
                if !ok {
                    return errors.New("data id must be a string")
                }
                md.MyData = append(md.MyData, myData)
            }
        default:
            // got something unexpected, handle somehow
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    b := `[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "key": "my_key"
  },
  [
    {
      "id": "some_id",
      "value": 12
    },
    {
      "id": "another_id",
      "value": 13
    }
  ]
]`

    m := MixedData{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(b), &m)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(m)

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/g8d_AsH-pYY

Hopefully there aren't any unexpected other elements, but they can be handled similarly.

Here is the second that relies more on Go's internal JSON parsing with the help of `json.RawMessage`. It makes the same assumptions about the contents of the array. It assumes that any objects will Unmarshal into `PublicKey` instances and any arrays consist of only `MyData` instances. I also added how to marshal back into the target JSON for symmetry:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type PublicKey struct {
    ID  int    `json:"id"`
    Key string `json:"key"`
}

type MyData struct {
    ID    string `json:"id"`
    Value int    `json:"value"`
}

type MixedData struct {
    Keys   []PublicKey
    MyData [][]MyData
}

func (md *MixedData) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    md.Keys = []PublicKey{}
    md.MyData = [][]MyData{}
    obj := []json.RawMessage{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(b), &obj)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, o := range obj {
        switch o[0] {
        case '{':
            pk := PublicKey{}
            err := json.Unmarshal(o, &pk)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            md.Keys = append(md.Keys, pk)
        case '[':
            myData := []MyData{}
            err := json.Unmarshal(o, &myData)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            md.MyData = append(md.MyData, myData)
        default:
            // got something unexpected, handle somehow
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (md *MixedData) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    out := make([]interface{}, len(md.Keys)+len(md.MyData))
    i := 0
    for _, x := range md.Keys {
        out[i] = x
        i++
    }
    for _, x := range md.MyData {
        out[i] = x
        i++
    }
    return json.Marshal(out)
}

func main() {
    b := `[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "key": "my_key"
  },
  [
    {
      "id": "some_id",
      "value": 12
    },
    {
      "id": "another_id",
      "value": 13
    }
  ]
]`

    m := MixedData{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(b), &m)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(m)

    enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    enc.SetIndent("", "    ")
    if err := enc.Encode(m); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ryZzaWKNcN0

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that combines [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) with the trick of using the default unmarshaler in a type that implements [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) by creating a new temporary type that aliases the target type.

The idea is that we unmarshal the incoming array into a raw message and ensure that the array length is what we expect. Then we unmarshal the individual array elements into the custom struct types using their JSON tag annotations. The end result is that we can unmarshal the `PublicKey` type in the usual way and the `UnmarshalJSON` code is not terribly difficult to follow once you understand the tricks.

For example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/s8Bc8Z1Oq4q)):

```
type PublicKey struct {
  ID   int    `json:"id"`
  Key  string `json:"key"`
  Data []MyData
}

type MyData struct {
  ID    string `json:"id"`
  Value int    `json:"value"`
}

func (pk *PublicKey) UnmarshalJSON(bs []byte) error {
  // Unmarshal into a RawMessage so we can inspect the array length.
  var rawMessage []json.RawMessage
  err := json.Unmarshal(bs, &rawMessage)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  if len(rawMessage) != 2 {
    return fmt.Errorf("expected array of length 2, got %d", len(rawMessage))
  }

  // Parse the first object as PublicKey using the default unmarshaler
  // using a temporary type that is an alias for the target type.
  type PublicKey2 PublicKey
  var pk2 PublicKey2
  err = json.Unmarshal(rawMessage[0], &pk2)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  // Parse the second object as []MyData in the usual way.
  err = json.Unmarshal(rawMessage[1], &pk2.Data)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  // Finally, assign the aliased object to the target object.
  *pk = PublicKey(pk2)
  return nil
}

func main() {
  var pk PublicKey
  err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstr), &pk)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("%#v\n", pk)
  // main.PublicKey{ID:1, Key:"my_key", Data:[]main.MyData{main.MyData{ID:"some_id", Value:12}, main.MyData{ID:"anorther_id", Value:13}}}

}
```