# Unmarshalling complex JSON into struct and accessing data (slice of slice of slices)

Tags: json, go, slice

I've been bashing my head about this for a while now. I have a JSON file that must be in the following format that I need to iterate through and use IF statements on in Go:

```
[
[
    {
        "configName": "customer"
    },
    {
        "config": [
            {
                "emailSubject": "New customer added"
            },
            {
                "text": "Hi test 2"
            },
            {
                "text": "added 2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
[
    {
        "configName": "customerAndUser"
    },
    {
        "config": [
            {
                "emailSubject": "New customer added"
            },
            {
                "text": "Hi, test 1"
            },
            {
                "text": "added 1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
]
```

And I want to put it into a struct, like this:

```
type Config [][]struct {
    configName string `json: configName`
    config     []struct {
        Text         string `json: text`
        EmailSubject string `json: emailSubject`
    } `json: config`
}
```

I can unmarshal the data fine, like this:

```
configData, err := ioutil.ReadFile("testing-config.json")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
var configDataUnmarshalled Config

json.Unmarshal([]byte(configData), &configDataUnmarshalled)
```

And then the data prints, sort of okay, but here is where things get a little strange: the print statement is returning blanks for the items that I do not specify to print. Here is a sample of what's printed when I print the unmarshalled data:

**Print output from unmarshalled data:**

```
[[{customer []} { [{ New customer added} {hi test 2 } {added 2 }]}] [{customerAndUser []} { [{ New customer added} {hi test 1 } {added 1 }]}]]
```

But then I can't seem to use IF statements or loop over the elements in the config key!

**IF statement being ignored in the for loop (see output below code)**

```
for _, configs := range configDataUnmarshalled {

    for _, configurations := range configs {

        fmt.Println("These are the top level elements in my struct: ", configurations.ConfigName)

        if configurations.ConfigName == "customerAndUser" {

            for _, config := range configurations.Config {

                fmt.Println(config)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is what is printed:**

```
These are the top level elements in my struct:  customer
These are the top level elements in my struct:
These are the top level elements in my struct:  customerAndUser
These are the top level elements in my struct:
```

From the FOR loop you can see that I want to access the data when a config is of a certain name, in this case "customerAndUser"

Here the IF statement is being ignored completely

I have two things I want to understand/solve:

1. How can I access the data following an IF statement
2. Why is the program printing blanks?

Desired output would be printing out the emailSubject, and the two Text element's data to the console for the config with name customerAndUser

**What should be printed:**

```
New customer added
hi test 1
added 1
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: So your JSON includes arrays of two objects, the first with a config name, the second with config.  But you're unmarshaling them into a single object, which obviously won't work.

Comment: But can't we have an array, containing two arrays? So the first array in the array contains the name and the config; then a second array with the same. I want to unmarshal these into structs

Comment: Sure you can. But that's not what you have. You have a single struct with two keys: `configName` and `Config`. But these keys are in separate objects in your JSON.

Comment: I'm relatively and obviously new to this, I assumed that setting type Config[][] struct could handle the arrays?

Comment: `type [][]struct` handles a slice of slices of struct. But that's not what where your problem is. Your problem is that your JSON has two objects, which you're trying to unmarshal into a single object.

Comment: Thanks, so you're saying I should convert ConfigName string to a struct within the Config struct?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying at all. I haven't suggested a course of action. I've just pointed out the cause of your problem. Your JSON is of the form `[{},{}]`, but you're trying to unmarshal it as if it were `[{}]`. At a theoretical level, this could be fixed by changing either the JSON, or by changing your Go struct. The latter is more complex to program, but if you don't control the JSON format, it's your only option.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try redoing the structs again. Sadly I don't control the JSON in any way

Comment: If you're re-doing the structs, make them simple. Something like:  `[ { "configName": "foo", "config": { "a": 1, "b": 2 } }, { "configName": "bar", "config": { ... } }`

Comment: Okay great, i'll try to get it working - thanks for your time

Comment: For unmarshaling the arrays see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48697961/unmarshal-2-different-structs-in-a-slice/48701156#48701156. Start with the innermost arrays (that have the emailSubject and text elements) and work your way outwards.

Answer (score 1):

json config is very smell. The struct contain `configName` and  `config` is two separately structs in a slice. `configName` have value so `config` is empty and backwards.  This will work when json like this.

```
{
        "configName": "customerAndUser",
        "config": [
            {
                "emailSubject": "New customer added"
            },
            {
                "text": "Hi, test 1"
            },
            {
                "text": "added 1"
            }
        ]
 }
```

So if you can't change json config format. This is solution

```
endUser := false

for _, configs := range configDataUnmarshalled {

    endUser = false
    for _, configurations := range configs {

        if configurations.ConfigName == "customerAndUser" {
            endUser = true
            continue
        }

        if !endUser || len(configurations.Config) == 0 {
            continue
        }

        for _, config := range configurations.Config {
            fmt.Println(config)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly I can't change the JSON file to fit my struct, it would have to be the other way around. Thank you though