# How to unmarshal this json string

Tags: json, go

I'm having some problem reading this type of json.

```
["Msg",{"cmd":"ack","id":"B81DA375B6C4AA49D262","ack":2,"from":"18094158994@c.us","to":"18099897215@c.us","t":1555446115}]
```

i try with many libraries.

```
type SEND struct {
    Mgs string `json:"Msg"`
    //SEND MSG
}

type MSG struct {
    CMD  string `json:"cmd"`
    ID   string `json:"id"`
    ACK  int    `json:"ack"`
    FROM string `json:"from"`
    TO   string `json:"to"`
    T    int64  `json:"t"`
}

func main() {
    data := `["Msg",{"cmd":"ack","id":"B81DA375B6C4AA49D262","ack":2,"from":"18094158994@c.us","to":"18099897215@c.us","t":1555446115}] `
    var dd SEND
    err := json.Valid([]byte(data))
    fmt.Println("Is valid XML?->", err)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &dd)
    fmt.Println("1", dd)
    fmt.Println("2", dd.Mgs)

}
```

Al always a receive empty
and the json it's valid

```
Is valid XML?-> true
1 {}
2 EMPTY
```

Comment: Try to use: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unmarshal 2 different structs in a slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48697961/unmarshal-2-different-structs-in-a-slice)

Comment: if you can somehow influence the structure of the json then I would try to fix it. It would be better to have a json in the form `{"Msg": {"cmd": "ack", ...}}`

Answer (score 3):

In this case you have array with `string` and `object` in your json, so you have to use `interface{}` on golang side, must be something like:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := `["Msg",{"cmd":"ack","id":"B81DA375B6C4AA49D262","ack":2,"from":"18094158994@c.us","to":"18099897215@c.us","t":1555446115}] `
    var d []interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &d)
    fmt.Printf("err: %v \n", err)
    fmt.Printf("d: %#v \n", d[0])
    fmt.Printf("d: %#v \n", d[1])
}
```

Result will look like:

```
err: <nil>
d: "Msg"
d: map[string]interface {}{"id":"B81DA375B6C4AA49D262", "ack":2, "from":"18094158994@c.us", "to":"18099897215@c.us", "t":1.555446115e+09, "cmd":"ack"}
```

So 1st element in slice `d` is string `Msg`,

and 2nd element in slice is map `map[string]interface {}`
and now you can do something else with this map.

Comment: To get the data just simple use  fmt.Printf("value is %v\n", d[1].(map[string]interface{})["cmd"])
 fmt.Printf("value is %v\n", d[1].(map[string]interface{})["id"])
 fmt.Printf("value is %v\n", d[1].(map[string]interface{})["ack"])
 fmt.Printf("value is %v\n", d[1].(map[string]interface{})["from"])
 fmt.Printf("value is %v\n", d[1].(map[string]interface{})["to"])
 fmt.Printf("value is %v\n", d[1].(map[string]interface{})["t"])