# Go parse json fixed size array

Tags: json, go, parsing

I've got some JSON data in the following format:

```json
{
  // Other data...
  "series": [
      [1709120579, 23.12],
      [1709120655, 24.69],
      [1709120660, 25.01],
      // etc..
  ],
  // Other data...
}
```

how would I be able to parse this Data into a struct like this:

```golang
type DataPoint struct {
    Timestamp int64
    Value float64
}

type JsonData struct {
    // other...
    Series []DataPoint
    // other...
}
```

but I can't find how to specifiy this,

here is what I currently have for testing:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type DataPoint struct {
    Timestamp int64   
    Value     float64
}

type JsonData struct {
    Data []DataPoint `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    jsonData := []byte(`{"data":[[132412,124.125],[3215124,23.123],[3214121224,21.42222]]}`)

    var data JsonData
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error unmarshalling JSON:", err)
        return
    }

    println(data.Data[0].Timestamp)
}
```

giving me:

````
Error unmarshalling JSON: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field JsonData.data of type main.DataPoint```
````

Comment: Make DataPoint implement encoding/json.Unmarshaler. E.g. via a helper slice and plain unmarshalling.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48697961/unmarshal-2-different-structs-in-a-slice/48701156#48701156. You can use json.Number instead of RawMessage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware the type of decoding I'm trying to do here is not supported by the available syntax, so the solution is to implement your own "parser" for the part which needs special attention.

This can be achieved separating the part which needs custom parsing into a separate struct (in my example below `DataPoint`) for which you can then implement the `UnmarshalJSON` function. What this allows you to do is Parse the present arbitrary JSON and then use that data to selectively choose individual elements you want to assign to the `DataPoint` struct.

```golang
func (d *DataPoint) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var records []json.RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &records); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(records[0], &d.Timestamp); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(records[1], &d.Value); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    jsonData := []byte(`{"data":[[132412,124.125],[3215124,23.123],[3214121224,21.42222]]}`)

    var data JsonData
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error unmarshalling JSON:", err)
        return
    }

    println(data.Data[0].Timestamp)
}
```

Thanks @Volker & @Peter

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**